# How to make llvm .bc file executable?

Tags: llvm

I have created a toy language that generates IR code and writes that code to a binary file with WriteBitcodeToFile (the C API). The result is a my-file.bc file.

In this file I have defined a main() function that takes no arguments and returns an int64 (should I change return type to byte maybe). How do I make this .bc file an executable. I'm running Linux.

Fredrik

Answer (score 23, accepted):

You can generate an object file with llc and then use GCC to create an executable:

```
llc -filetype=obj my-file.bc
gcc my-file.o
./a.out
```

You can read more about llc on http://llvm.org/docs/CommandGuide/llc.html.

Answer (score 1):

It is possible to execute a bc-file with lli command. However that doesn't create a stand alone executable product.

Answer (score 1):

There's always the option of using llc to compile to assembly from which you can generate an executable.

http://llvm.org/docs/CommandGuide/llc.html

Comment: Yes, and it says "The assembly language output can then be passed through a native assembler and linker to generate a native executable." How would I do that in Linux?

Comment: I think perhaps my suggestion is not a good path to take if you're unsure of how to use an assembler and linker. Instead, you might have more success attempting an alternative build method which does not result in a final bitcode file and instead moves straight to producing an executable.

Comment: Yes, to be honest it was 15 yrs ago on Win95/Dos since I last used assembler and maybe 13 yrs since I last linked binaries. Mind that I never used Linux back then. So it's a new tool set for me. I wish to get kick started on this. I can't seem to satisfy the google spirit.